# Write polynomial as word using SymPy

Tags: iteration, sympy

I'd like to input a polynomial and have an output of the polynomial written out as a 'word' (in the sense of a free algebra where all powers are collapsed into a product of variables). For example,

1. `INPUT x**2, OUTPUT x*x`
2. `INPUT (x*y**2)**3, OUTPUT x*y*y*x*y*y*x*y*y`

If anybody knows a way to do this, it would be much appreciated (I am a beginner to Python). Thanks!

I have had a look at SymPy expand which, for the second example gives the output:
`x*y**2*x*y**2*x*y**2`.

But then this is still not fully reduced, and this gives the same problem as of the first example. I think a loop to replace the power operator ** with the corresponding number of multiplications should work, but I am unsure how to implement this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way might be to use the `evaluate(False)` context manager in order to replace powers with multiplications:

```py
from sympy import *
var("x, y")

def func(base, exp):
    values = [base]*exp
    return Mul(*values)

with evaluate(False):
    expr = x**2 + (x*y**2)**3
    res = expr.replace(Pow, func)
    print(res)

#out: x*x + (x*(y*y))*(x*(y*y))*(x*(y*y))
```

Then you would have to manually remove parentheses.

Comment: @LaurenS If this answers your question then you should accept it.